# Approximating Pi with Polygons

Tags: performance, c, numerical-methods

I wrote a program that approximates Pi by using polygons. I used the formulars in the picture beyond. 
In my code they are called `innerPoly` (\$c_{2n}\$) and `outerPoly` (\$C_{2n}\$).

And since you can calculate the circumference of a 2n-polygon with knowing the circumference of a n-polygon you will get the circumferences \$C_8\$, \$C_{16}\$, \$C_{32}\$ etc., knowing \$C_4\$.

$$
\begin{array}{l}
c_{2n} =& 2 \sqrt{2n^2-n\sqrt{(2n)^2-c_n^2}} \qquad&\textrm{for the inner polygon, with}\ c_4=4\sqrt{2} \\
C_{2n} =& \frac{4 n C_n}{2n + \sqrt{(2n)^2 + C_n^2}} &\textrm{for the outer polygon, with}\ C_4=8
\end{array}
$$

My thoughts are:

1. Would it make it anyhow better when I have a function called `void PiApproximation()` that writes my values to stdout already? I mean technically you can always put your full code into the `main()`-function, but when you have to use the same code-parts over and over again you should make a own function of it and call it, when u need it. 
   So I guess in  this case it will make no difference if I use an own function or calculate the circumferences and print it in the main-function.
2. What else can I improve?

pi_approx.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INNER_FOUR 4*sqrt(2); //circumference c_4 of the inner tetragon(square) 
#define OUTER_FOUR 8 //circumference C_4 of the outer tetragon

int power(int n, int p);

int main(void)
{
  int n = 4;
  double innerPoly = INNER_FOUR;
  double outerPoly = OUTER_FOUR;

  printf("PI-APPROXIMATION USING POLYGONS\n");
  printf("===============================\n\n");
  printf("    n    I      c_n/2      I       C_n/2     I\n");
  printf("---------I-----------------I-----------------I\n");

  for (int i=3; n<=8192; n=power(i,2), i++)
  {
    printf("   %4d  I   %1.8lf    I    %1.8lf   I\n", n, innerPoly / 2, outerPoly / 2);

    innerPoly = 2 * sqrt(2 * n*n - n*sqrt(4 * n*n - innerPoly*innerPoly)); //formular c_2n
    outerPoly = (4 * n * outerPoly) / (2 * n + sqrt(4 * n*n + outerPoly*outerPoly)); //formular C_2n
  }

  return 0;
}

int power(int n, int p)
{

  int pBuffer = 1;

  for (int i=1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    pBuffer *= p; 
  }

  return pBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You asked,

   > Would it make it better if I had a function called `PiApproximation`?

   The code in `main` does just one thing so it would not be an improvement to introduce a new function like this — the question would then be, what's the point of `main`?
2. There is a dependency between the initial value of `n` and the initial values of `innerPoly` and `outerPoly`. It would make sense to put all the initialization code together.
3. Because `n` can never be negative it could be unsigned.
4. The loop:

   ```
   for (int i=3; n<=8192; n=power(i,2), i++)
   ```

   is quite hard to follow because the loop variable is `i` but the termination condition is on a different variable `n`. Because the loop variable `i` is not used, it would be easier to follow the logic if you wrote:

   ```
   for (; n <= 8192; n *= 2)
   ```

   (This also avoids the need for the `power` function.)
5. The `l` modifier has no effect on the `printf` format specifier `%f`, and so should be omitted.

Comment: I see, thank you for the helpful and fast answer!

Comment: I don't know the C preprocessor very well, but those `#define` scare me: iirc doing something like `double sum = INNER_FOUR + OUTER_FOUR` or anything with code after the macro could break in interesting ways. What's the correct way to deal with that?

Comment: @CAD97: Parenthesize the macro expansion (see the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html)).

Comment: In my case I only use this constant circumferences of a 4-polygon as a start-value of my calculation, i.e. I do not really use them in a formular, where I can immediately see what this constant would mean in a determined context.

Comment: So in my case I could directly write on the variables `innerPoly`, `outerPoly` my start-values at the begin of the `main()`-program. What do you think about that?