# Approximation of error-function erf(x)

Tags: performance, c, numerical-methods

The code beyond approximates the error-function `erf(x)` with following formular \$erf(x)=1-(a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3)e^{-x^2})\$ for \$x\geq0\$ inclusive the identity \$erf(-x)=-erf(x)\$.

1. Is it okay to end the program in the middle of a code with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`? I just tried to avoid it and came to following solution, where the program always ends with `return 0` at the end of the main-programm: 
   https://codepaste.net/ek8ed5 So the question is whats's the more correct way?

(I hope a moderator can paste this code section in here please, because somehow I didn't make it work to show it as nicely formatted code, sorry!)

2. What else can I improve?

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define p 0.47047
#define a_1 0.3480242
#define a_2 -0.0958798
#define a_3 0.7478556


double ErrorFunction(double x);

int main(void)
{
  double x = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter any value x to show erf(x): ");

    if (scanf_s("%lf", &x) != 1)
    {
      printf("error: invalid input\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\n erf(x)=%f\n\n", ErrorFunction(x));
    }

  } while (x != 0);

  return 0;
}

double ErrorFunction(double x)
{
  double t = 0;

  if (x < 0)
  {
    x = -x;
    t = 1 / (1 + p*x);
    return -(1 - (a_1*t + a_2*t*t + a_3*t*t*t)*exp(-(x*x)));
  }
  else
  {
    t = 1 / (1 + p*x);
    return 1 - (a_1*t + a_2*t*t + a_3*t*t*t)*exp(-(x*x));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- DRY. Actual computations are repeated twice, which is always a signal for improvement:

  ```
  if (x < 0) {
      t = 1 / (1 - p*x);
  } else {
      t = 1 / (1 + p*x);
  }

  result = compute_the_formula(t, x);

  if (x < 0) {
      result = -result;
  }
  return result;
  ```
- Try to cut down multiplications. Instead of

  ```
  a_1*t + a_2*t*t + a_3*t*t*t
  ```

  consider

  ```
  t*(a_1 + t*(a2 + t*a_3)))
  ```

  Three multiplications instead of original six is not only faster, but generally more accurate.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. Actually I should really implement `erf(-x)=-erf(x)` according to this exercise.  And it is also called identity.

Comment: 2. I.e. the less multiplications you have the more accurate it is, because you have less rounding errors?

Comment: 3. What do you say to my v1- and v2-`main()` in my starting post (codepaste.net)?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> double ErrorFunction(double x);
> ```

Would `erf` be a better name?

---

> ```
>     if (scanf_s("%lf", &x) != 1)
> ```

> ```
>       printf("\n erf(x)=%f\n\n", ErrorFunction(x));
> ```

Why the inconsistency between `%lf` and `%f`?

---

Following up on a comment you made to another answer:

> Actually I should really implement `erf(-x)=-erf(x)` according to this exercise

The best way to do that from the point of view of 1) self-documenting code; 2) not accidentally breaking it in maintenance is

```
double ErrorFunction(double x)
{
  if (x < 0) return -ErrorFunction(-x);
  ...
```

Comment: Oh yeah that is good idea! So I only have one code line that computes my approximation instead ot two!
1. I didn't use `erf` as name, because I got this compiler warning: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273 or is it ok to ignore this one? I thought that you always should avoid any compiler Warnings. (I use VS 2017)

Comment: 2. I used `%f`in my printf, because it makes no difference to `%lf`by using it in a `printf` and I got the advice from here too:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160846/approximating-pi-with-polygons?rq=1 (point 5)

Comment: And when are you trying to use it on 'scanf' it won't work, because pointers aren't promoted to anything, but variables are. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f) But I guess i should always stick to the same `%`? I. e. `%lf`for doubles,  `%f`for floats etc.

Comment: @physics, 1. Makes sense that the logical name is already used. Still, I'd favour namespacing the name. In extremis, `my_erf`. 2. Fair enough. Gareth knows C better than I do.